# VBA Right-Function returning wrong data type

Tags: vba

I have written a very simple code which returns the last 6 characters of every active cell within a range.

The code works pretty good until it finds a particular cell in which the characters to be returned should be: "MARC01". Unfortunately it returns a date type character (01.Mrz).

By using the normal excel formula it works fine, that is why I would expect it to work with a Macro as well.

Here you can see my code which takes the strings from column "A" and enters it in column "B":

```
    Range("B12").Activate

    Do
      ActiveCell.Value = Right((ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value), 6)
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
```

Comment: I recommend you change ".Value" to ".Formula", as, in short, .Value may provide different results depending on formatting, whereas .Formula is more or less the core numerical / text result itself. Not sure if that fixes your specific problem.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - neither .Formula nor .Value2 does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel likes to change anything that looks like a possible date to a date.  To force this not to happen put a `"'"` in front of the formula.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "'" & Right((ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value), 6)
```

This will force it to stay text.  The down side to this is, if it is a number it will be saved as text.

Answer (score 3):

Excel likes to try to interpret certain data, rather than just leaving it as is. It especially does that with strings that look like dates, and with numeric entries.

Two ways to workaround are

- Put the text prefix character in front of your string. This is usually a single quote.  (see Scott's answer for code)
- Format the cell as Text before you place the value there.

---

```
 Sub foo()
 Range("B12").Activate

    Do
      ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
      ActiveCell.Value = Right((ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Formula), 6)
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

With this simple goal, I don't know why you need VBA looping.

You can just mass set the formular1c1 to `=RIGHT(RC[-1],6)`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Right6()
    Const R6LeftCol = "=RIGHT(RC[-1],6)"
    Dim oRng As Range, lRow As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set oRng = Range("B12")
    Range(oRng, Cells(lRow, "B")).FormulaR1C1 = R6LeftCol
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```